# lua 'require' duplicating table

Tags: module, lua, reference, require

What I am trying to do is; use a module to create two distinct and separate tables but what seems to be happening is; if I have already used 'require' then it will give me a reference to the previous require what I *really* want is just the value/a copy of the module. I cannot use 'dofile' because 1). I need to use relative paths and 2). I am building this in Corona for android and as I understand 'dofile' does not work well with .apk.

Here is my code.

This is my main.lua

```
foo = require('modules.myModule')
bar = require('modules.myModule')

bar:changeName()

assert(foo.name ~= bar.name)
```

this is in %cd%/modules/myModule

```
local M = {
    name = "hai",
    changeName = function(self)
        self.name = 'not_hai'
    end
}
return M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your module can return constructor of `M` instead of `M`

---

Your module:

```
return 
   function()  -- this is a constructor of M
      local M = {
         name = "hai",
         changeName = function(self)
            self.name = 'not_hai'
         end
      }
      return M
   end
```

---

Your main script:

```
foo = require('modules.myModule')()
bar = require('modules.myModule')()

bar:changeName()

assert(foo.name ~= bar.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

as variant you can use this unrequire function:

```
function unrequire(m)
    package.loaded[m] = nil
    _G[m] = nil
end

foo = require('myModule')
unrequire('myModule')
bar = require('myModule')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is way I write module

```
local M = {}

function M.new()
  local myTable = { name = "hai" }

  myTable:changeName ()
    self.name = 'not_hai'
  end

  return myTable
end

return M
```

*Usage:*

```
local m = require('myModule')

foo = m.new()
bar = m.new()

bar:changeName()
```